# Recover data on Fragment without call BDD

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, datas are loading while the splash screen is displayed. When it's done, the user can enter new data that are displayed in a fragment and insert in the database. Moreover, new data entered by the user allows to compute a variable that is also displayed in a custom view (in the fragment) and insert in the database. So, outside the splash screen, I'm using only `db.insert()`.

I have several fragments and I want to recover my datas when I swith from one fragment to another without call the database with `db.get()`

Now, when I switch to another fragment (using navigation drawer) and go back to the previous one, my data are no more displayed...

Indeed, I want to limit call to the database when the app is running.

### UPDATE

A little update to be more explicit :)

I have an Activity handling a Navigation Drawer. For the moment, I switch between 2 fragments (Frag1 & Frag2).

In the first fragment I have a custom view (named for example CustomView1) and some TextView (TextView1 & TextView2).
Through an item in action bar, TextView1 can be updated by the user. The value set for TextView1 is also insert in a database. Automatically, TextView2 is updated with the previous value of TextView1 as below :

```
     /**
     * Listener to see if TextView1 change
     **/

    TextView1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String X;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            X = charSequence.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            TextView2.setText(X);
        }
    });
```

When I switch to Frag2 and back to Frag1, TextView1 & TextView2 are empty and nothing is display.

I tried to use `onSaveInstanceState` like this :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putFloat("mTextView1", mTextView1);
    savedInstanceState.putFloat("mTextView2", mTextView2);        
}
```

and in onCreateView :

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state
        mTextView1 = savedInstanceState.getFloat("mTextView1");
        mTextView2= savedInstanceState.getFloat("mTextView2");
    }
```

My savedInstanceState is always returning null...

This is how I switch between fragment :

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            Fragment1 Frag1 = new Fragment1();
            FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,Frag1,"TAG1");
            fragTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            Fragment2 Frag2 = new Fragment2 ();
            FragmentTransaction fragTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragTransaction1.replace(R.id.content_frame,Frag2,"TAG2");
            fragTransaction1.commit();
            break;
    }

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mSection[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

### Solution

I am using `SharedPreference` during user action to store data I want (moreover, these data are insert in the database)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();                            
                               editor.putFloat("mKey1", value1);
                               editor.commit();
```

In onCreate, I get data I stored previously :

```
sharedPref = this.getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             if(sharedPref!=null) {
                variable1 = sharedPref.getFloat("mKey1",DEFAULT_VALUE);
             }
TextView1.setText(String.valueOf(variable1));
```

As TextView1 is updated, TextView2 is update too with the listener taking the previous value of TextView1.

Comment: How did you switch between? I mean by using fragment.attach() & .detach, .add() & .remove(), or .show() & .hide(). Which one you used? Try to use others and test.

Comment: I use .replace(). I will test others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using `SharedPreference`

Comment: @summea - see my answer above. Hope it help u